# How to fully remove an external library in a project?

Tags: android, eclipse

I would like to fully remove all the links to an external library in my project. How can I do that ?

What I did:

- Right click on project folder => Properties => Android => remove the library in the right panek
- Right click on project folder =>Build Paths => Configure build paths =>In the right panel: the folder relative to the library can be expanded; I manage to remove one of the resources in this expanded fodler but not the others (and consequently not the root folder)

The library (.jar) is still visible in my project above the assets folder and I don't manage to remove it. Below how it looks (cannot be remove by right click and delete (gray)):

[image: jar file which cannot be removed]

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: If .jar file is visible in asset folder then you have to manually remove it. select that .jar file and delete.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't manage to remove this file (I edited my question to add a screenshot). When I right click on it, the "delete" option is gray (not available). How can I remove this file ? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe You have to go:

right click on your project:

properties > select "Android"

Under "Library", remove the library you want.

It maybe some libraries include other libraries so you couldn't remove it from where you have tried.

Answer (score 4):

Right click on the jar file -> Build Path -> Remove from Build Path

Answer (score 2):

Open settings.gradle and delete:

`"include ':librayname'"`

Then delete lib file from app Myproject/app folder.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to remove an External Library after following these steps:

1. Remove compile entry from build.gradle (app)
2. RESTART Android Studio.

Answer (score -1):

Following steps worked for me :

1. Right click on JAR file in libs folder
2. Choose option Refractor and then select Safe Delete Option
3. Delete this entry from build.gradle --> compile files('libs/)
4. open Android Studio terminal and execute this command --> gradlew clean

jar file will be deleted but Code you have used from the jar file will still be there in java files. you can manually delete that.